# Column not Repeat on each page + SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I make report using SSRS

Then I want to repeat left column on each page

I set this properties in Tablix properties but it's not work

[image]

and this is my Tablix

[image]

So how to repeat whole left column on each page

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the checkmark in "Repeat header rows on each page" instead of "Repeat header columns on each page".

Comment: OP wants to repeat only one column, that is, most left column, not all header.

Comment: Ok. I think it impossible because I try to repeat column on other tablix that contain 1 row group it's can repeat whole left column but when I remove row group it' can't repeat